# Gitlab CI - Permission denied

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, ssh-keys

I've been trying to setup the CD for my project in Gitlab but I'm getting the following error in the pipeline:

bash: line 151: /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/ssh-key.pem: Permission denied

Cleaning up project directory and file based variables

ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

This is my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
default:
  image: amazonlinux:latest

deploy-prod:
  only:
    - main
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - ls -la
    - pwd
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( yum update -y && yum install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - cat $SSH_KEY_EC2
    - echo "$(cat $SSH_KEY_EC2)" >> ~/.ssh/ssh-key.pem
    - chmod 400 ~/.ssh/ssh-key.pem 
    - cat ~/.ssh/ssh-key.pem
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - yum update -y
    - apt-get -y install rsync
  script:
    - >- 
  ...
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: You try to use cat on a variable, that won't work. try these:
`echo "$SSH_KEY_EC2"`    
`echo "$SSH_KEY_EC2" > ~/.ssh/ssh-key.pem`

Answer (score 0):

Considering the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/) also use the same chmod (400 for private keys, 700 for .ssh, make sure first exactly where, in your script, the error occurs:

- at the `echo >>`,
- at the `chmod 400`,
- or at the `cat`?

That way you can start debug the permission issue, making sure the permission are properly set.